# How to check if array contains 3 consecutive duplicates?

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to return true if input (n) contains 3 duplicates in a row, else return false.

My code:

```
def got_three?(n)
  n.each_cons(3) { |a, b, c| a == b && b == c ? true : false }
end
```

this is returning an error and I'm unsure as to why. Any help?

Comment: _"this is returning an error"_ – show it, please.

Comment: "this is returning an error" is not a precise enough error description for us to help you. *What* doesn't work? *How* doesn't it work? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ?

Comment: Can you provide a *precise* specification of what it is that you want to happen, including any and all rules, exceptions from those rules, corner cases, special cases, boundary cases, and edge cases? Can you provide sample inputs and outputs demonstrating what you expect to happen, both in normal cases, and in all the exceptions, corner cases, special cases, boundary cases, and edge cases? For example: what should be returned if the array is empty? What if there are fewer than 3 elements? What if `n` is not an array but an infinite stream?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this one

```
n.each_cons(3).any? { |a, b, c| a == b && b == c }
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked! I assume that the .any? just check if there is any, then if not returns nil?

Comment: If one block is true the result is true, otherwise false

Answer (score 0):

No need to chain methods, just use `Enumerable#each_cons` with a block:

```
array.each_cons(3) { |f, s, t| break true if f == t && s == t}
```

Returns `true` if the array contains 3 duplicates in a row, otherwise `nil` (simple use `!!` if you need exactly `true` or `false`).

Benchmarks:

```
require 'benchmark'

array = (0..1000).to_a.push(*[3, 3, 3])

Benchmark.bmbm(20) do |x|
  x.report(:chain) do
    array.each_cons(3).any? { |a, b, c| a == b && b == c }
  end

  x.report(:one_block) do
    array.each_cons(3) { |f, s, t| break true if f == t && s == t}
  end
end
```

Result:

```
                           user     system      total        real
chain                  0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.000167)
one_block              0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.000101)
```

As you can see, this solution is more than 1.6x times faster. Happy coding :)